# How to load image from assets in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-image

I have hundreds of png files in assets folder and I want to load them into `Image` composable. But what I can use only images in drawable folder.
how to load images from assets into `Image`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Halifax solution works but I have some performance issue with it. by using Coil it is much smoother and cleaner.

in build.gradle (:app) :

```
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.2.2")
```

and then:

```
AsyncImage(
            model = "file:///android_asset/images_folder/image.png",
            contentDescription = "",
        )
```

Comment: I tried to show a svg file but it did not appear - any help?

Answer (score 4):

Example:

```
var bitmapState by remember{ mutableStateOf<Bitmap?>(null) }
val context = LocalContext.current

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    bitmapState = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.assets.open("assetsImage.png"))
}


if (null != bitmapState) {
    val bitmap = bitmapState!!.asImageBitmap()
    Image(
        bitmap = bitmap,
        "assetsImage",
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        colorFilter = null
    )
}
```